# AsyncTask ; doInbackground() not called after calling method onPreExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I did added async library at my project and checked already, I don't know why code flow doesn't go in to asynctask

Code

```
public void doMysql()
{
    Log.v("doMysql", "accessed");

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");

            String msg = "";

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.16.100.172:52273/mysql");

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myday", Integer.toString(day_picker.getYear()) + 
                    addZero(day_picker.getMonth() + 1) + 
                    addZero(day_picker.getDayOfMonth())));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mystar", changeStar(day_picker.getMonth() + 1, day_picker.getDayOfMonth())));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mybt", changeBloodType(blood_picker.getValue())));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mynum", "" + myPhone.getText()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yournum", "" + partnerPhone.getText()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myregID", regid));
            try {
                Log.v("setEntity", "before");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.v("setEntity", "after");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                Log.v("UnsupportedEncodingException", "");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            //172.16.101.28
            try {  
                Log.v("post", "before");
                HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.v("post", "after");
                Log.v("HttpResponse ",httpresponse.getEntity().toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.v("ClientProtocolException", "ClientProtocolException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("IOException", "IOException");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return msg;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");

        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

I have a log statement in the code 'Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");'

But it doesn't show up in the logger 'Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");'

Comment: try .execute() instead of .execute(null, null, null);

Comment: results is same... Why do you think that would be a solution? Locally, it worked very well with '.execute(null,null,null)'

Comment: possibly another asynctask is still executing

Comment: `I got a log 'Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");'` ??? typo?

Comment: @njzk2 Really?? It could... but How can I find ??

Comment: @brightstar At my log cat , 'AsyncTask : doInBackground' is marked...

Comment: @LKM well, if you have 'doInBackground' in your logcat then your asynctask executes fine

Comment: `I got a log 'Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");'

But It doesn't show me that log ' Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");'` what?

Comment: @LKM to check if your problem is caused by other asynctask blocking yours, you can try executing it in parallel (depends on android version): `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null);`.

Comment: My Async Task does not work: this is an exception for only one place: however: when I want to update the screen when the user comes to the last item in my ListView using onScroll Listener. When nothing worked I switched to usual thread for the background operation and handler to update Ui for postExecute.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should execute your task with executor

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Because in lower versions of Android all AsyncTasks were executed at single background thread. So new tasks might be waiting, until other task working.

In lower versions in Android (actually on pre-HONEYCOMB) you can't execute AsyncTask on executor.

Change your code to

```
public void executeAsyncTask()
{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.e("AsyncTask", "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "doInBackground");
            String msg = null;
            // some calculation logic of msg variable
            return msg;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Log.v("AsyncTask", "onPostExecute");
        }
    };

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB/*HONEYCOMB = 11*/) {
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I was in the same situation.

1. I made a call `AsyncTask.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` passing true
2. Then I assumed (I was wrong) that the `doInBackground()` of this task was now interrupted

By adding logs statements I realised that the very first `asyncTask` was still running ... thus preventing another `asyncTask` to execute. It's `doInBackground()` method was running an infinite while loop so I simply had to change condition to consider all the possible "break" cases...

Answer (score 6):

### Doing this not working for you?

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

I was already doing this and the problem was still there, the problem was I was using `AsyncTask` to run long background tasks that do run forever, so the `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s worker threads were already occupied.

In my case `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` (use debugger to get your executor properties) was having the ff properties:

```
maximumPoolSize = 3
largetsPoolSize = 2
corePoolSize =2
```

So disabling one of the long running asyncTasks made my doInBackground code to run but that is not the right solution.

The right solution is I moved long running tasks into custom threads rather than using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Alternatively you can define your own custom executor - it is not so hard, just see how it is done in AsyncTask, and make it with more threads in the pool

Answer (score 5):

Quoting Android Documentation for [Async Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

Use this snippet for triggering AsyncTask:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
   asyncTaskInstance.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
else
   pdfPageChanger.execute(params);
```