# Android Studio doInBackground not getting hit

Tags: android

Fiddling around with android for the first time and I can't find any solutions to my exact issue. Even though this does seem like a common problem.

When I debug my app it doesn't go into the downloadTask activity.

I have seen solutions mention `asyncTask.execute()` but that doesn't work.

I at a bit of a loose end. Why is my app not going into `doInBackground`/downloadTask?

**DownloadTask (doInBackground)**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(urls[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int data = reader.read();
        while (data!=-1){
            char current = (char) data;
            result += current;
            data = reader.read();
        }

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        Log.d("CREATION", "GOT TO THE FIRST PART");
        JSONObject weatherDatas = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));
        Double tempInt = Double.parseDouble(weatherDatas.getString(("temp")));
        int tempIn = (int) (tempInt*1.8-459.67);
        String placeName = jsonObject.getString("name");
        Log.d("CREATION", placeName);
        MainActivity.temperatureTextView.setText(String.valueOf(tempIn)  + "F");
        MainActivity.placeTextView.setText(placeName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static TextView placeTextView;
static TextView temperatureTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    placeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    temperatureTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureTextView);



    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    Double lat = location.getLatitude();
    Double lng = location.getLongitude();
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
            String.valueOf(lat) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(lng) + "&appid=193a308a7dbf9e4d0d8c0b09ff296a88");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You have called `task.execute()` `AsyncTask` should run . Do have have `INTERNET` permission in manifest ?

Comment: How you check that you don't enter `doInBackground`? If placing breakpoint, you may not see it break because you are in a different thread.

Comment: @ADM Good point. But without INTERNET permission wouldn't an exception would beraise...

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890618/asynctask-doinbackground-not-called-after-calling-method-onpreexecute/26890971)

Comment: Yeah i though maybe OP put  breakpoint after `openConnection()`. And not in `catch` block . This is just a test case . @JoeBoggs on which API version you are testing ?

Comment: I have set INTERNET permission in manifest, @ADM API version for?

Comment: API Version for Device . Which OS ? Is it working now or not ?

Comment: @ADM Its not working yet, API v26

Comment: @Afshin if i cant use breakpoints, how can I see if its accessed downloadTask or not?

Comment: how are you checking ? Put a `Log` on first line of `doInBackground()` and see if it prints .

Comment: @ADM Did that and it doesnt print, also added breakpoints and ran in debug but doesnt hit

Comment: @JoeBoggs you need to switch threads, if you do that breakpoint will trigger. or you can use `Log`.

Comment: @Afshin I've used log and it didnt log anything so i dont think switching threads will give any new knowledge

Comment: @JoeBoggs You are sure that you are checking your emulator logcat? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#systemLog  because this is a mistakes that I still sometimes do.

Comment: @Afshin yes definitely checking the emulator log

Comment: @JoeBoggs to make sure, you have allowed your app to use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission,isn't it? Because if you have not, you will return at permission check and you will not create AsyncTask.

Comment: @Afshin yes i've allowed ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `onCreate()` method as following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    placeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    temperatureTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureTextView);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();

    task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
            String.valueOf(300) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(400) + "&appid=193a308a7dbf9e4d0d8c0b09ff296a88");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And I checked, it **enters** `doInBackground()` (I just copy/pasted your `AsyncTask` in a new project). I tested it on API level 25 though. So My guess is something is wrong with your permission requesting at runtime, because you need to request ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at runtime.

Because you have not requested ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at run time, check of permission fails and you return. So you will not create `AsyncTask` at all.

Check requesting permissions here: [Requesting permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I have ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />``` and ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>``` in my manifest. Is that not enough? how do i access it in runtime?

Comment: @JoeBoggs this is the problem. For INTERNET permission is enough, but for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, you need to request it at run time: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html